# 3rd party background check company is asking for w2 and/or paycheck stubs and/or tax records

Tags: background-check, self-employment

I was a member of two LLC's (on of which I currently work for) and the 3rd party background check company is asking for w2 and/or paycheck stubs and/or tax records.

My problem is that since I am a member in the LLC I do not issue myself a w2, but I do issue a K1 at the end of the year for taxes.   My tax transcripts do not show individual companies.

Any advice?

Comment: have you explained the situation to the requestor and ask them what they would like?

Answer (score 5):

> Any advice?

Talk to the 3rd party background check company, and ask them how they would like you to handle this scenario.

Comment: I did and they said they would have to talk to the employer to see if any of those would work